# Understanding the general cubic formula? ("Changing the choice of a cubic root"?)

Tags: calculus, polynomials, cubics

Paraphrasing [Wikipedia > Cubic Equation > General cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula), and ignoring special cases and caveats, it says:

The cubic equation:

$$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$$

can be solved as follows:

Let:

$$\Delta_0 = b^2 - 3ac$$
$$\Delta_1 = 2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d$$

$$C = \sqrt[3]{{\Delta_1 \pm \sqrt{\Delta_1^2 - 4 \Delta_0^3}}\over{2}}$$

One of the roots is:

$$x = - {{1} \over {3a}}(b + C + {\Delta_0 \over C}) $$

**The other two roots can be obtained by changing the choice of the cube root in the definition of C**.

What does it mean "changing the choice of the cube root in the definition" of C?

Comment: Indeed it's poor wording. I think it refers to the $\pm$ -sign in the equation for $C$.

Comment: @MattiP.: But that would yield just one other root, don't we need three roots?

Comment: You would multiply something like $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt3 i}{2}$ called “primitive roots”. This basically$ (-1)^{1/3}$. See this [snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LOIf.jpg) here.

Comment: @TymaGaidash No, the values you mentioned are the other two cube roots of unity ($1$), not $-1$

Comment: Cube roots of $1$ are NOT the same as cube roots of $-1$

Comment: A sign change in the quadratic equation has no influence on the resulting root, except in terms of numerical stability, as commonly discussed for quadratic equations.